# pointerEvents={'none'} not work in Android Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, touch-event, user-interaction, pointer-events

I am trying to disable touch event on a view. I found that we can disable it by using **pointerEvents={'none'}**. When I added it, then it's working in iOS, but not working in android. Is this bug or Is there any other way to disable user event on both Platform?

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you got the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try `removeClippedSubviews={Platform.OS == 'android'}`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?